# Expression language & style="background-image:url

Tags: html, url, styles, background-image, el

I'm using Thymeleaf (Spring Boot project). The code below init image in the center of screen (from this .html https://colorlib.com/etc/coloshop/single.html:

```
<div class="col-lg-9 image_col order-lg-2 order-1">
    <div class="single_product_image">
        <div class="single_product_image_background" style="background-image:url(images/single_2.jpg)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to replace line "images/single_2.jpg" with ${product.mainImage} but I'm not able to to dit properly. ${product.mainImage} include url address from database. EL expression generally works in this document but not in the code above.

Doesn't work:

```
style="background-image:url("${product.mainImage)")
```

If I use:

```
style="background-image:url(${product.mainImage})
```

I have "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "body" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ""error.

How to use EL properly in this example? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I think just change $ to #:

```
style="background-image:url('#{product.mainImage}')";
```

Comment: With this solution I have "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "div" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"." error.

Comment: ya you need to complete the quote like following: style="background-image:url("#{product.mainImage)")"

Comment: ^^ It generates "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "div" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"." Combinations "url(#{product.mainImage})"" and url('#{product.mainImage})" don't work but without error.